Estimating the left hand second derivative of a specific polynomial at $1$ given imprecise evaluations
I have a polynomial that looks like $$f(x)=n-\sum_{j=1}^nx^{d_j}$$ where $d_j\in\mathbb N$ (with $0\in\mathbb N$ and the convention that $0^0=1$). The only access I have to $f$ is blackbox access to the evaluations of $f$ in $[0,1]$, but the evaluations are imprecise, that is, on querying it the value of $f(x), x\in [0,1]$, it returns a value randomly from $\left((1-\epsilon)f(x),(1+\epsilon)f(x)\right)$ for some fixed $\epsilon>0$. The only gurantee we have is that the mean of the values at a specific $x$ is $f(x)$ (it can be assumed that the variance is $\epsilon$, but I would rather not use it unless really required).
The object I want to estimate is $f''(1)$ from the left (from now on, I keep the mention of left hand derivative implicit). More specifically, I want to calculate an $\widehat{f''(1)}$ such that for $\delta>0$, $$\mathbb P\left(|\widehat{f''(1)}-f''(1)|\ge \delta\right)$$ has a good upper bound (independent of $n$, $d_j$s and maximum degree specifically).
I have tried the naive approach of estimating the whole polynomial by assuming $d_j\le d$ for all $j$ and using interpolation. The bound I get has a $n$ (with no assumptions on the variance) or has a $d$ (with assumption on variance). For the second case it is clear where the dependency on $d$ comes from; I am after all querying at $d+1$ many points.
But derivatives can be estimated without needing to estimate the whole polynomial. That is, one can use constant number of queries to estimate it. For example one can use
$$f''(x)\approx \frac{2 f(x) - 5f(x-h) + 4 f(x-2h)- f(x-3h)}{h^2}$$ for some fixed gap $h$. The issue is the minus signs is causing me a lot of headache in the estimation.
I noted that the polynomial has more structure that I am not exploiting. The polynomial is (strictly) decreasing after $x=0$, and has a root at $x=1$.
Is there a good estimate that I can produce? I am a little stuck, so any hints or solutions are appreciated! Thanks in advance.
Edit : So I should mention why the negative signs are causing issues. Consider multiplicative estimates $\hat a, \hat b$ for two numbers $a$ and $b$ respectively. Then one notes that $$\hat a-\hat b\le (1+\epsilon)a-(1-\epsilon)b=(1+\epsilon)(a-b)+2\epsilon b$$ So even if $a$ and $b$ are big but close, $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ might not be close. This causes the whole estimation using the finite difference method kind of very sticky.

What about the queries of $x$ for $f(x)$? Are these values of $x$ given or we allowed to choose them? If the latter holds then are we receive the results of all queries at once or we allowed to choose each next  query given the results of the previous queries?

@AlexRavsky You are free to choose the values of $x$, with the only restriction being that they have to come from $[0,1]$. And you are also free to choose the 'next' value of $x$ depending on the previous results (this is called adaptive querying, and yes we allow it).

The question looks not easy. So if you shall receive no answer here you can ask it at MathOverflow.
